# SQL Query that returns all records when the where clause subquery has invalid column name...?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So there's a query in a legacy app that never worked, because the subquery was wrong.  The SQL query is below:

```
SELECT CompanyName
FROM Companies
WHERE CompanyID = (SELECT CompnyID FROM Users WHERE UserID = 123)
```

As you can see, in the subquery, CompanyID is missing the a and is spelled wrong. Yet, when you run this entire query, it returns all records in Companies. But when you run the subquery, it says "Invalid Column name 'CompnyID'."  Why does this happen?  Why doesn't this query error?  This is kind of confusing to me, so I'm curious why this query runs.  I assume it's some quirk with subqueries?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a column CompnyID in Companies?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this is your real query.  Your description would suggests that there is a column in `Companies` called `CompnyID`.

Table aliases are a good idea.  When using subqueries, they should be mandatory.  You think you are writing:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName
FROM Companies c
WHERE c.CompanyID = (SELECT u.CompnyID FROM Users u WHERE u.UserID = 123);
```

But, because `u.CompnyID` does not exist, it is interpreted as:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName
FROM Companies c
WHERE c.CompanyID = (SELECT c.CompnyID FROM Users u WHERE u.UserID = 123)
```

This will return all columns where the two values are the same.